# Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core 2 throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I receive following exception when I try to use custom DbContext in `Configure` method in `Startup.cs` file. I use ASP.NET Core in version 2.0.0-preview1-005977

> Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Communicator.Backend.Data.CommunicatorContext' for the parameter 'dbContext' of method 'Configure' on type 'Communicator.Backend.Startup'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Communicator.Backend.Data.CommunicatorContext' from root provider.

This exception is also thrown in case when I try to receive other instance.

> Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Communicator.Backend.Services.ILdapService'  `...`

Here are my `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<CommunicatorContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddCookieAuthentication();
    services.Configure<LdapConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("Ldap"));
    services.AddScoped<ILdapService, LdapService>();
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, CommunicatorContext dbContext, ILdapService ldapService)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseWebSockets();
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path == "/ws")
        {
            if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                WebSocket webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                await Echo(context, webSocket);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    });
    app.UseMvc();
    DbInitializer.Initialize(dbContext, ldapService);
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Quoting documentation

> [**Services Available in Startup**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup#services-available-in-startup)
>
> ASP.NET Core dependency injection provides application services during
>   an application's startup. You can request these services by including
>   the appropriate interface as a parameter on your `Startup` class's
>   constructor or one of its `Configure` or `ConfigureServices` methods.
>
> Looking at each method in the `Startup` class in the order in which
>   they are called, the following services may be requested as
>   parameters:
>
> - In the constructor: `IHostingEnvironment`, `ILoggerFactory`
> - In the `ConfigureServices` method: `IServiceCollection`
> - In the `Configure` method: `IApplicationBuilder`, `IHostingEnvironment`,
>     `ILoggerFactory`, `IApplicationLifetime`

You are trying to resolve services that are not available during startup,

```
...CommunicatorContext dbContext, ILdapService ldapService) {
```

which will give you the errors you are getting. If you need access to the implementations then you need to do one of the following:

1. Modify the `ConfigureServices` method and access them there from the service collection. i.e.

   ```
   public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
       services.AddDbContext<CommunicatorContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
       services.AddCookieAuthentication();
       services.Configure<LdapConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("Ldap"));
       services.AddScoped<ILdapService, LdapService>();
       services.AddMvc();

       // Build the intermediate service provider
       var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

       //resolve implementations
       var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetService<CommunicatorContext>();
       var ldapService = serviceProvider.GetService<ILdapService>();
       DbInitializer.Initialize(dbContext, ldapService);

       //return the provider
       return serviceProvider();
   }
   ```
2. Modify the `ConfigureServices` method to return IServiceProvider, `Configure` method to take a `IServiceProvider` and then resolve your dependencies there. i.e.

   ```
   public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
       services.AddDbContext<CommunicatorContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
       services.AddCookieAuthentication();
       services.Configure<LdapConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("Ldap"));
       services.AddScoped<ILdapService, LdapService>();
       services.AddMvc();

       // Build the intermediate service provider then return it
       return services.BuildServiceProvider();
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
                         ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {

       //...Other code removed for brevity

       app.UseMvc();

       //resolve dependencies
       var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetService<CommunicatorContext>();
       var ldapService = serviceProvider.GetService<ILdapService>();
       DbInitializer.Initialize(dbContext, ldapService);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. If I can add more, after testing both options, I found that I still need to modify `ConfigureServices` from returning `void` (by default) to return `IServiceProvider`, in order for the second option to work.

Comment: Had a similar problem. Making `ConfigureServices()` return the `IServiceProvider` alone made it possible to resolve my dependencies via `IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetService<T>()`. I didn't need to inject the `IServiceProvider` into the `Configure()` method.

Answer (score 32):

The solution from NKosi works because by invoking `services.BuildServiceProvider()` yourself without parameters you are not passing the `validateScopes`. Because this validation is disabled, the exception is not thrown. This doesn't mean that the problem is not there.

EF Core `DbContext` is registered with a scoped lifestyle. In ASP native DI, the container scope is connected to instance of `IServiceProvider`. Normally, when you use your `DbContext` from a Controller there is no problem because ASP creates a new scope (new instance of `IServiceProvider`) for each request and then uses it to resolve everything within this request. However during the application startup you don't have request scope. You have an instance of `IServiceProvider` that is not scoped (or in other words in root scope). This means you should create a scope yourself. You can do it like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
    using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CommunicatorContext>();
        var ldapService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILdapService>();
        // rest of your code
    }
    // rest of Configure setup
}
```

The `ConfigureServices` method can remain unchanged.

**EDIT**

Your solution will work in 2.0.0 RTM without any changes since in RTM scoped service provider will be created for Configure method https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/pull/1106.

Answer (score 24):

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 and newer you can simply inject the scoped service you need into the `Configure` constructor, like you tried to do initially:

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
    CommunicatorContext dbContext,
    ILdapService ldapService)
{
  // ...
}
```

This is a lot easier, thanks to the improvements in [#1106](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/pull/1106).

Comment: It is the natural way to solve the problem of the question. Thank you.

Comment: Best way to do it with the 2.0 RTM

Answer (score 17):

```
.UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => 
            options.ValidateScopes = false)
```

add this in Program.cs after `.UseStartup<Startup>()`

Works for me

[Documentation Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/12/announcing-ef-core-2-0-preview-1/)

Comment: Thanks. Works in Asp.Net Core 2.1 Api App , too. What is that ValidateScopes doing actually?

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can create a service scope within your `Configure` method:

```
var scopeFactory = ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<CommunicatorDbContext>();
    DbInitializer.Initializer(dbContext, ldapService);
}
```

Although, as mentioned on Slack, don't do this ;-)

Comment: What is wrong with this? Why do you suggest not to do this. I have now this: ```using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope()) scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IInitDatabase>().InitAsync().Wait();``` should I do this some other way?

Comment: Mentioned what on Slack? Why shouldn't this be done? @krzysztof-branicki 's answer has upvotes suggesting this and has been posted months earlier, why haven't you taken this into your answer?