# Run database migrations using Entity Framework ASP.NET Core on application start

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to automatically run a database migration on application start in ASP.NET Core 2.0 and EntityFramework Core 2.0.

I have found [Run database migrations using Entity Framework core on application start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282138/run-database-migrations-using-entity-framework-core-on-application-start). However, my connection strings are stored in the environment variables so they would not be found until the `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` are called in the `Configure` method.

How to call `the db.Database.Migrate()` or how to properly do the database migration (in Azure Web App) via Continuous Deployment and staging environments?

```
public class Startup
{
    private IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDbContext<ClientContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppService")));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();

        this.Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    }

    // public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ClientContext db)
    // {
    //     db.Database.Migrate();
    // }
}
```

Comment: Why not just call `db.Database.Migrate()` at the end of the `Configure()` method?  After connection strings are set.

Comment: If I add the `ClientContext db` parameter to the `Configure` method, the `ClientContext` will get instantiated before the `Configure` call is made. The `ClientContext` gets the `options` as a constructor parameter which tries to retrieve the `AppService` connection string before the `Configuration` object is configured (or event instantiated). Or is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on you comment above I would try this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    app.UseMvc();

    this.Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    var db = serviceProvider.GetService<ClientContext>();
    db.Database.Migrate();
}
```

This is manually resolving the `ClientContext` after the Environment variables have been set up and therefore it won't fail the parameter injection.

EDIT:  The error you're getting can be resolved by following the steps in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44191372/616304)

Comment: I guess that the ClientContext life time is managed by the runtime so there is no need to add "using" statement, right?

Comment: I am getting `Cannot resolve scoped service 'AppService.ClientContext' from root provider.`.

Comment: See my edit above, no point me re-writing out those steps as well :-)

Comment: The only thing I am not very happy of is that the app needs to work under a full sql admin to make this work. But that is another issue.